# Error on AWS server: Is "dev-xvdb.device: Job dev-xvdb.device/start timed out" harmless?

Tags: server, systemd, aws

I noticed these error messages in the systemd logs on all our AWS servers running Ubuntu (on both 16.04 and 18.04):

```
dev-xvdb.device: Job dev-xvdb.device/start timed out.
Timed out waiting for device dev-xvdb.device.
Dependency failed for /mnt.
mnt.mount: Job mnt.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/xvdb.
systemd-fsck@dev-xvdb.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-xvdb.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dev-xvdb.device: Job dev-xvdb.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

The functionality of the servers is not affected as far as I can see. The messages are always the same, start appearing at startup and repeat every few hours, although there is no clear pattern:

```
Jul 24 20:13:50
Jul 25 00:05:19
Jul 25 06:09:19
Jul 25 12:32:19
Jul 25 13:13:08
Jul 25 19:19:49
Jul 26 01:31:09
Jul 26 06:11:02
Jul 26 10:09:19
Jul 26 14:05:19
Jul 26 19:09:19
...
```

The messages also appear on idle servers, so I do not think it is related to the current workload.

**Question:**

- Do you know what the error message is about?
- Can it be fixed, or is it safe to ignore it?

Additional system information:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs / ext4 defaults,discard 0 0
/dev/xvdb /mnt auto defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service,comment=cloudconfig 0 2
```

Comment: At a previous time did you have an AWS EBS volume attached to this instance and then removed it? The error is caused by the system trying to mount a disk (volume) to /mnt and it does not exist.

Comment: @JohnHanley That is interesting. I see it on instances with use a AMI snapshot (created by Packer or manually by hand). On another instance that was started from an official Ubuntu AMI, I don't see it. Could be related to the internals of creating the AMI snapshot. Maybe it temporarily attaches an EBS volume. Then when you later create an instance based on that image, it still remembers that device with is no longer present at that point.

Comment: In 10 years of working with AWS I have never seen this problem from an AMI or snapshot. Can you expand on "I see it on instances with use a AMI snapshot (created by Packer or manually by hand)." with more details?

Comment: @JohnHanley I was guessing, but I got it wrong. When I checked the logs again, I can see that it is unrelated to how the AMI was created. Instead it has to do with the "/dev/xvdb" entry in fstab and that the device does not exist, as you explained. Not sure why the entry exists in the first place. Maybe I can figure it out, but as "/mnt" is not used on the server, the error itself looks harmless.

Comment: If your EC2 instance only has one volume attached, then I would delete the fstab entry so that you are not polluting your log files.

Comment: Did you by any chance import that image using ec2 import images? This file seems to exist b/c of cloud-init but only if that image was imported via ec2 import image process. There is a 'nofail' flag in there, inserted by cloud-init, so systemd should ignore it but that does not always seem to be the case. If that's the case, you can remove the entry from /etc/fstab without any negative effects.

Comment: Guys, I have exact same scenario and same error. I created this from AMI and the original ec2 also has this and xvdb found nowhere. In my fstab, the line looks like this 
`/dev/xvdb   /mnt    auto    defaults,nofail,comment=cloudconfig 0   2`.